# Which way do electrons transfer?

Tags: electrons

When an object is rubbed against another object, it transfers electrons, that much I know. 
But what determines the way it's going?
Against the object that's being rubbed against, or the object that's rubbing?

I tried searching on the internet for a while, but nothing popped up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do that charge gets transferred while rubbing?] (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/528458/how-do-that-charge-gets-transferred-while-rubbing) . The magic search word is "triboelectric series".